# How to remove columns in 2D numpy array if one element is smaller or larger than a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Right now I have a 2-D numpy arrays that represents the coordinates pixels of an image

```
points = [[-1,-2,0,1,2,3,5,8] [-3,-4,0,-3,5,9,2,1]]
```

Each column represents a coordinate in the image, e.g:
array[0] = [-1,-3] means x = -1 and y = -3

Right now, I want to remove columns that either has x less than 0 && more than 5 or y less than 0 && more than 5

I know how to remove elements of a certain value

```
#remove x that is less than 0 and more than 5
     x = points[0,:] 
     x = x[np.logical_and(x>=0, x<=5)]

#remove y that is less than 0 and more than 5
     y = points[1,:] 
     y = y[np.logical_and(y>=0,y<=5)]
```

Is there a way to remove the y that shares the same index with the x that is deleted?(in other words, remove columns when either the condition for x deletion or y deletion is satisfied)

Comment: Simply `OR` it. So. with `x = points[0,:]; y = points[1,:]` : `points[:,np.logical_and(x>=0, x<=5) | np.logical_and(y>=0,y<=5)]`?

Comment: Since, you are removing, you might have to use `AND` instead.

Comment: I got an error saying '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' . points is a ndarray but when I use x = points[0,:], it becomes a list.

Comment: Start off with : `points = np.array(points)`.

Comment: Thanks, but then I got an error saying "too many indices for array" instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `list` to `ndarray`, then create a mask of boolean and reassign `x`, `y`. The nested `logical_and` mean you create a mask of `x>=0 and x<=5` and `y>=0 and y<=5`, then the `AND` operator ensure that if once `x[i]` deleted, `y[i]` got deleted as well

```
points = [[-1,-2,0,1,2,3,5,8], [-3,-4,0,-3,5,9,2,1]]
x = np.array(points[0,:])
y = np.array(points[1,:])

mask = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(x>=0, x<=5), np.logical_and(y>=0, y<=5))
# mask = array([False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False])

x = x[mask] # x = array([0, 2, 5])
y = y[mask] # y = array([0, 5, 2])
```

Comment: If you prefer a short syntax you could also write `mask = (x>=0) & (x<=5) & (y>=0) & (y<=5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.compress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) along the axis=1 to get the points you need:

```
np.compress((x>=0) * (x<=5) * (y>=0) * (y<=5), points, axis=1)

array([[0, 2, 5],
       [0, 5, 2]])
```

where I have assumed that `x`, `y` and `points` are numpy arrays.